# ReactJS: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 with .NetCore in HTTPS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, asp.net-core, .net-core

I use ReactJS to develop my application, it was fine before, but suddenly this error happens:

> GET https://localhost:44368/static/js/0.chunk.js net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

I do not know what is happening here, it was fine before. How can I fix this?

Comment: I was getting this issue but I didn't change anything and I don't get the issue anymore. Maybe a recent Windows Update or VS update helped?

Comment: I've experienced this behavior when there is an exception while writing to the response stream. I had a `NullReferenceException` in a call to `IHtmlContent.WriteTo()`, and that was enough to generate the error. Attaching a debugger to the process immediately revealed the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and experienced the same problem. This is what I did to resolve it:

Removed 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extentions' Nuget package from the project's Dependencies/Packages, and then installed the latest version (Installed 5.0.6)

[image]

Cleaned and rebuilt the solution and it started working again.

let me know if it works for you!

Comment: You sir, saved my life. I have to upgrade the .net version to 5.0, then upgrade the spa service extension to 5.0.6. It works now.

Comment: Nice, I am glad it worked. I also had to upgrade to .Net Core 5. I really wonder why the default project framework was set to an older .Net Core version to begin with.

Comment: I am just curious to know how come you debug this type of problem. How do you get to know that this package is causing problems

Comment: I wish I remembered the complete answer to your question as I fixed this more than a month ago. I remember some messages in the visual studio terminal hinted me about a possible problem in Nuget packages. It took a whole day for me to find it though!

Answer (score 12):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but wanted to drop a note saying had the exact same experience as JTM and think that the Win10 update seems to be the likely suspect. .Net Core project that worked fine last night with no changes has stopped working post-update.

Comment: I had this happen to me as well. All working fine last night but today, not at all. If I publish the app and deploy on IIS it works, but it won't work in debug from Visual Studio. I've lost a whole day of development time trying to figure this out, and still no luck!

Comment: Also, I am using .NET 5.0.

Comment: I have now managed to get it to run by going to the server project Properties page > Debug and then unticking "Enable SSL". I'll try turning it back on after a VS/Windows update and see if the underlying issue has been resolved.

Comment: The disable SSL option didn't work for me, so I ended up uninstalling the Windows update in question which solved the issue for now. Annoying solution unfortunately but it worked.

Comment: FYI, another option for .net core based web apps that seems to work is to bypass IIS Express and run the web project directly.

Comment: Actually I will say that the best solution would be to uninstall both KB5003637 and KB5003254 as once I did that I was able to continue working as before. There appears to be some bugs in these patches that is breaking IIS express ssl functionality.

Comment: Uninstalling KB5003637 solved this problem for me. We are on .NET Core 3.1 w/ SPA extensions for hmr etc.

Answer (score 7):

This solution does not work for dotnet core.  I've tried updating SpaServices.Extensions to the latest version 3.1.16.

A temporarily solution is to disable SSL under Web Server Settings.

Comment: I tried updating a few dependencies like "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" to 3.1.16 but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Alan Barber's answer. I was looking for solution without upgrading my .NET Core version (3.1) to 5.

My project back to normal after uninstalled the window update patch (KB5003637).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by uninstalling a recent Windows patch, KB5003637. https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/06/11/windows-10-kb5003637-update-could-break-your-taskbar

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following update

> Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB5003637)

After removal, it will ask you to restart the computer. It will then install an older security update: probably `KB5003173` which won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me after the windows update and rolling that back was not possible because of corporate policy. I found a solution in this developer community link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Failed-to-load-resource:-net::ERR_HTTP2_/1446262 (Specifically the the one by Kevin Pilch).

I added the registry entries ( 2 of them to turn off HTTP2) and it worked.
Another option if the  registry edit is not working is to install Fiddler and keep it running. Fiddler will force HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/2

Relevant sections from his post

Start the Windows Registry Editor.

1. Navigate to the registry key 2.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters.
2. Add 2 new REG_DWORD values, EnableHttp2Tls and EnableHttp2Cleartext, to this
   registry key.
3. Set both values to 0.
4. Reboot the server .

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears if the maximum size of the request is too large. The default `maxrequestbytes` that defines this limit is 16KB.

If you're running in a development environment, you can easily go over this limit if you are running a number of sites on localhost that use cookies (some auth cookies can take up a bit of space). Clearing cookies should help resolve this specific issue.