# ASP.NET Core: SPA bundle is requested over http not https

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, single-page-application

I have this configuration for SPA in .NET Core web server (`Startup.cs`)

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    // ...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    // ...
}
```

I have enabled the HTTPS configuration for the debugging.

[image]

If I remove the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and disabled the `https` debugging, it works. But if I enable the `HTTPS this error shows up when loading the SPA bundle:

> GET https://localhost:44355/static/js/0.chunk.js net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

It was fine before, I do not know what the cause of this. I suppose the application is requesting the bundle over `HTTP and not` HTTPS.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the `IIS Express`, but the problem still persists. I do not know what the cause of this, please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to run visual studio as an administrator, and you can refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417219/ssl-connection-connection-reset-with-iisexpress/22818853#22818853

Comment: I have tried with admin privilege but it does not fix it.

Comment: I fix it with @emasnavi solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747270/reactjs-neterr-http2-protocol-error-200-with-netcore-in-https/67767129#67767129